# Combine params.required with apipie param_group

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apipie

How can I combine Rails' `params.require` with apiepie's `param_group` to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 0):

I know that it's a little bit late to reply, but here's how to do it:

1. Create a controller that extends ApiPie:

```rb
class ApiController < ActionController::Base extend Apipie::DSL::Concern
```

2. Define `param_groups` in that controller:

```rb
def_param_group :param_errors do
    error code: 200, desc: "Success"
    error code: 400, desc: "Error"
    error code: 401, desc: "Unauthorized"
    error code: 404, desc: "Not Found"
end
```

3. Extend this controller from your second controller:

```rb
class MyCustomController < ApiController
```

4. Call the `param_group` before your function using:

```rb
param_group :param_errors, ApiController
def my_method
    # ...
end
```